# new Scanner not waiting for input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

When executed, the following code will not wait for user input:

```
  private int getInt(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()){
      System.out.println("There is a token");
      if (sc.hasNextInt()){
        result = sc.nextInt();
      } else {
        sc.next();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("There is not a token");
    sc.close();
    return result;
  }
```

I am calling this function immediately after calling another functions that gets a string rather than an int. This functions works correctly.

```
private String getString(String prompt, String pattern, String errorMessage){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!sc.hasNext(pattern)){
      System.out.println(errorMessage);
      sc.next();
      System.out.println(prompt);
    }
    String result = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    return result;
  }
```

I have seen other similar questions where people try to read in data using multiple methods in succession, normally nextLine() then nextInt and don't consume the end of the token first, but I don't think this is what's happening here.

The programme doesn't wait for user input and just skips straight to the debugging line "There is not a token". Any help would be appreciated!

The calling code is as follows:

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s, you are %d and were born in %d. You are %s tall", m.getString(), m.getInt(), m.getBirthYear(), m.convertHeight(m.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Sidenote: Don't close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, as this will close the underlying stream aswell.

Comment: I note the docs say "If an invocation of the underlying readable's read() method throws an IOException then the scanner assumes that the end of the input has been reached." I suspect this is what's happening here; try calling `System.in.read()` yourself at the start of the method, I expect you'll get an `IOException` that may give you more context as to the underlying problem

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks for your response. Will this not result in memory leaks though? Or would it be better to just have one scanner wrapping system.in and pass it in to getString and getInt?

Comment: @maloomeister Actually I think that's more than a sidenote - closing the stream would mean there *are* no more tokens to read.  Since `getInt` is called after `getString` this is almost certainly what's happening.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I took your suggestions and did get an IOException saying that the stream was closed. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LucasGracia Calling `close()` wouldn't have any impact on memory leaks - it's about what strong references exist.  `sc` will be eligible for collection once the method exits (and you don't want to GC the `System.in` stream...).  That said, I feel it would be better to create just one `Scanner` to represent the tokenised input, then call whatever methods you want/need to on it.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle "_ closing the stream would mean there are no more tokens to read. Since getInt is called after getString this is almost certainly what's happening._" - That is EXACTLY what was happening. I posted a solution with an explanation.

Comment: @LucasGracia this is why knowing how to troubleshoot properly pays off. In order to figure out your issue, I ran each portion independently (I only used the two methods you showed). Doing this let me know both method were working. At that point, I deduced the issue was how they were being invoked. There, I noticed the problem was that the second invocation (`m.getInt()`) resulted in a `NoSuchElementException` - which you neglected to mention here. A quick search for that problem gave me information I needed to fix this problem. It took me less than 5 minutes to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
public class ScannerDemo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ScannerDemo m = new ScannerDemo();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf(
            "Hello %s, you are %d and were born in %d. You are %s tall",
            m.getString(sc), m.getInt(sc), m.getInt(sc), m.getString(sc));
        sc.close();
    }
    
    private int getInt (Scanner sc) {
        int result = sc.nextInt();
        return result;
    }
    
    private String getString (Scanner sc) {
        String result = sc.next();
        return result;
    }
}
```

When given this input:

```
Hector
53
1968
5'8"
```

Produces the following output:

```
Hello Hector, you are 53 and were born in 1968. You are 5'8" tall
```

The main problem is calling `sc.close()` inside each method. When you close this method, you actually close the input stream associated with the `Scanner` object and once you close it, there is no way to reopen it.  I also took out all unnecessary code. You can insert the prompts as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. This example is close to what I had implemented following the above comments and it works as expected.